# Why plone.api doesn’t have find?

Tags: python, plone, zope, plone-4.x

I trying create a script to find a exist folder, if not create this folder.

But when a call `find` from `plone.api` the output is `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'find'`

Bellow my terminal:

```
$ bin/instance -O intranet debug
>>> from plone import api
>>> from zope.site.hooks import setSite
>>> portal = app['intranet']
>>> setSite(portal)
>>> folders = api.content.find(context=portal, portal_catalog='Folder')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'find'
>>>
```

What is wrong in my case?
I used this documentation [plone.api.content.find](http://docs.plone.org/4/en/external/plone.api/docs/content.html#content-find-example)

Comment: `api.content.find` has been added at some point. Maybe you are using an older version?

Comment: @LucaFabbri in `/eggs/plone.api-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO` I have this `Name: plone.api Version: 1.1.0` in pypi the latest version is `1.5`. I'll proceed with upload, the result I going to post here. Thx!

Comment: You're right, I updeted to 1.5 and works his output is a brain. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need update `plone.api` to a version with support to method find. Like said by @LucaFabbri. In my case the product was update to `1.5.0`.